# "Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "id". Int32 array index expected" crash when gathering json

Tags: c#, json

I am currently gathering json from a url but i recieve an error that i have never experienced before looking like this:

`Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "id". Int32 array index expected`

This is how the JSON looks (an example of 1 item, there are more of these):

```
[  
   {  
      "id":19205,
      "company_id":2658,
      "external_link":"",
      "county":{  
         "id":12,
         "name":" ",
         "future":"",
         "infrastructure":""
      },
      "category":{  
         "id":5,
         "name":""
      },
      "company":{  
         "id":2658,
         "company_info":[  

         ]
      },
      "merits":[  

      ],
      "reqs":[  
         {  
            "id":56548,
            "ad_id":19205
         },
         {  
            "id":56549,
            "ad_id":19205
         },
         {  
            "id":56550,
            "ad_id":19205
         },
         {  
            "id":56551,
            "ad_id":19205
         },
         {  
            "id":56552,
            "ad_id":19205
         }
      ],
      "contact":null
   }
]
```

How i gather the json:

```
static public async Task<JArray> getData()
    {
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient();
        try
        {
            var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync("https://mydata.com");
            var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var jsonResult = JArray.Parse(resultString);
            return jsonResult;
        }

        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

How i try to use it and where the error occurs:

```
var getData = await dataApi.getData();

foreach (var jobs in getData)
{       
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(getData["id"].ToString()); //CRASH: `Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "id". Int32 array index expected
}
```

How would I need to adjust my code in order to successfully gather the JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to reference the array within the for loop, try:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(jobs["id"].ToString());
```

or

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(jobs.id.ToString());
```

You might also need to parse your Json for it to be interpreted by c# code
see [this post about parsing Json with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c/)

Comment: Ok but the example json i posted is just 1 row, there are multiple rows that i need to get out. (I will update the post with that to be more clear)

Comment: Are you trying to get multiple rows at the same time? Because the for loop will iterate over the array giving you the value of each item in the array

Comment: Yeah i am trying to get all the rows straight away. (I add the data to a list)

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez That's what the for loop is for right?

Comment: The foreach loop yes. But i get the `Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "id". Int32 array index expected` when i try to write the different id's in the log

Comment: That's because you are using the _whole_ array `getData` rather than a single item for the array `jobs` as declared in your foreach loop

Comment: Hmm so how would i need to adjust the code then in order to loop out every result?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "loop out every result", could you elaborate? Or do you mean 'do something' to each result?

Comment: Yea exactly. I want to compare each "jobs["id"].ToString()" to see if they match another ID i have stored as a string. If they do i want to add every data in the JSON to that list

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez You're getting the error because you have `getData["id"]`.  Change it to `jobs["id"]` and it will work.  Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KAksJM

Comment: Ah jesus christ. Lack of sleep :/ Sry i didnt see it sooner